# google maps android, all markers being loaded within circle

Tags: android, google-maps, geometry, markers

I am using a circle and trying to use its latitude and longitude values to load markers from a database that are within distance, the problem is, it is loading all the markers, rather than just the ones within the circle.

Can anyone point out where I'm going wrong? Code:

```
float[] distance = new float[10];
for(int i=0; i<jArray.length(); i++)
{
    JSONObject jsonData = jArray.getJSONObject(i);

    databaseMarkerData.add(new BasicNameValuePair("name", jsonData.getString("name")));
    databaseMarkerData.add(new BasicNameValuePair("address", jsonData.getString("address")));
    databaseMarkerData.add(new BasicNameValuePair("description", jsonData.getString("description")));
    databaseMarkerData.add(new BasicNameValuePair("rating", jsonData.getString("rating")));
    databaseMarkerData.add(new BasicNameValuePair("lat", jsonData.getString("lat")));
    databaseMarkerData.add(new BasicNameValuePair("lng", jsonData.getString("lng")));
    databaseMarkerData.add(new BasicNameValuePair("estType", jsonData.getString("estType")));
    databaseMarkerData.add(new BasicNameValuePair("reliability", jsonData.getString("reliability")));

    String latText = jsonData.getString("lat");
    Double lat = Double.parseDouble(latText);

    String lngText = jsonData.getString("lng");
    Double lng = Double.parseDouble(lngText);

    getMarkerDataArray.add(new MarkerData(jsonData.getString("name"), jsonData.getString("address"), jsonData.getString("description"),
            jsonData.getString("rating"), jsonData.getString("reliability"), lat, lng, jsonData.getString("estType")));



    Location.distanceBetween( lat, lng, circle.getCenter().latitude, circle.getCenter().longitude, distance);

    if( distance[i] < circle.getRadius())
    {
        plotMarkers(getMarkerDataArray);
    }
}
```

this is my plotMarkers function just in case it is needed:

## plotMarkers()

```
private void plotMarkers(ArrayList<MarkerData> markers)
{
    if(markers.size() > 0)
    {
        for (MarkerData markerData : markers)
        {
            // Create user marker with custom icon and other options
            MarkerOptions markerOption = new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(markerData.getLat(), markerData.getLng()));

            Marker currentMarker = googleMap.addMarker(markerOption);
            markerDataHashmap.put(currentMarker, markerData);

            googleMap.setInfoWindowAdapter(new MarkerInfoWindowAdapter());
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are more than one problem.

One is the [first element](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/Location.html#distanceBetween%28double,%20double,%20double,%20double,%20float[]%29) of `distance` is what you should use:

```
    if( distance[0] < circle.getRadius()){
         plotMarkers(getMarkerDataArray);
    }
```

And you just need one element array `float[] distance = new float[1];`

Two is this

```
   if( distance[i] < circle.getRadius())
    {
    plotMarkers(getMarkerDataArray);
    }
```

that `getMarkerDataArray` is a list that is filled regardless whether the distance condition is met or not and used in `plotMarkers` for every time it is. I think what you want is

```
   for (...){
      if( distance[0] < circle.getRadius()){
         getMarkerDataArray.add(new MarkerData(...));
      }
   } 
   plotMarkers(getMarkerDataArray);
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but unfortunately it still loads the markers that are outside the bounds of the circle